# How to insert items into a database using URL parameters with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to get JSON items from a database and also insert them. I originally created it following the tutorial on the CodeIgniter site, which uses a form to send data to the database, and that worked correctly. I'm attempting to amend this code so that you can write to the database by putting the field values in the URL string. So, to GET data, it's http://www.mcbiscuit.com/index.php/robots/. This calls the Robots controller.

You can also put http://www.mcbiscuit.com/robots/(Name) to see the database entry for that robot. I need to fix the set method so that you can use a URL like this http://www.mcbiscuit.com/robots/create/(Name)/(StarsIn)/(Function) to write an entry with these details to the database, but whatever I do, it passes NULL values for these. How do I make it insert the records correctly? I've read everything I can about writing to databases with PHP, and CodeIgniter API calls and such, and I cannot find a solution.

Controller code:

```
<?php 
class Robots extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('robot_model');
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($this->robot_model->get_robots(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            //$data['Robots'] = $this->robot_model->get_robots();
            //$data['title'] = 'Robots';

            $this->load->view('robots/index');
        }
        public function view($name = NULL)
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($this->robot_model->get_robots($name), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            $this->load->view('robots/view');
        }

        public function create($name, $starsIn, $function)
        {
            $this->robot_model->set_robots($name, $starsIn, $function);
            $this->load->view('robots/success');
        }
}
```

Model code:

```
<?php
class Robot_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_robots($name = FALSE)
        {
            if ($name === FALSE)
            {
                    $query = $this->db->get('Robots');
                    return $query->result_array();
            }

            $query = $this->db->get_where('Robots', array('Name' => $name));
            return $query->row_array();
        }

        public function set_robots($name, $starsIn, $function)
        {
            //$data = parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);

            $data = array(
                'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'StarsIn' => $this->input->post('starsIn'),
                'Function' => $this->input->post('function')
            );
            var_dump($data);

            return $this->db->set('Robots', $data);
        }
}
```

Routing code, because I'm not sure this is correct:

```
$route['robots/create'] = 'robots/create';
$route['robots/(:any)'] = 'robots/view/$1';
$route['robots'] = 'robots';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Comment: You can use [$this->uri->segment($n)](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment) or [$this->uri->rsegment($n)](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::rsegment) to reach those values. Also, put default controller at beginning of **routes.php** file. [Last line in document](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html): *The reserved routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.*

Comment: Thanks! I changed the route.

Comment: No problem. It is most important you solved your issue. #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah routing for `robots/create` is incorrect, it should be

```
$route['robots/create/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'robots/create/$1/$2/$3';
```

This way codeigniter knows that anything after `create/` are considered as GET/method parameters.

But you really shouldn't be using GET parameters to insert/update/delete records, because for example I could post a link/picture somewhere on some website and put a redirect link to your `robots/create/some/idiotic/data` and anyone who is logged in your website that clicks my link/picture will insert rubbish data into your database.

Google for CSRF attack to learn more about it and how to protect against it.

Also looking at `set_robots` method, you are trying to create a `$data` array with 
`$this->input->post()` but you are not using POST so your array should just be:

```
$data = array(
    'Name'     => $name,
    'StarsIn'  => $starsIn,
    'Function' => $function
);
```